# Is there a way to run es6 components, specifically promises and generators, in aws lambda functions

Tags: ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony, aws-lambda

ES6 usage requires `--harmony` flag in node v0.12.3.

Is there a way to do so for an aws lambda function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These answers are a bit out of date. AWS announced support for Node.js 4.3.2 runtime in April 2016. 4.3.2 supports ES6. It is also completely backwards compatible. More details available here:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/node-js-4-3-2-runtime-now-available-on-lambda/

Answer (score 3):

You can use [babel](https://babeljs.io) to transform es6/es7 to be compatible with node 0.10.x:

http://www.rricard.me/es6/aws/lambda/nodejs/2015/11/29/es6-on-aws-lambda.html

EDIT:

There is also a really cool AWS lambda deployer called [Apex](http://apex.run/) with that you can transform and deploy es6/es7 code easily! Examples: https://github.com/apex/apex/tree/master/_examples/babel-webpack

EDIT2:
There is an other AWS lambda deployer called [Gordon](https://github.com/jorgebastida/gordon/) which also helps you integrate lambda with other services such as:

- APIGateway
- Scheduled CloudWatch Events (cron)
- CloudWatch Events
- Dynamodb Streams
- Kinesis Streams
- S3

They also have a lot of useful examples

Answer (score 1):

AWS Lambda use `v0.10.36`, but anyway I think we can try in this way

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
var child = spawn('node', [ "--harmony", "es6.js" ], {
  cwd: __dirname
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, use [bluebird](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird)
. Any file that requires to make use of promises, get bluebird in scope.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

    Promise.aPromise()
    .then(function () {
       console.log('ftw!');
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
       console.log(err, 'do not forget to catch errors. ever!');
    })
```

As far as generators are concerned, we are out of luck. `bluebird` requires minimum `v0.12+` and at the time of writing lambda is still stuck in `node v0.10.36`